# Ramanujan's asymptotic formula for $p(n)$

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

The following expression is the exact formula of [partition function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html).

[image]

Ramanujan's asymptotic formula for  $p(n)$ is following

$$p(n)\sim\frac{1}{4n \sqrt{3}}e^{\pi \sqrt{2n/3}}$$

Can I use *Mathematica* to reduce exact formula to the Ramanujan's asymptotic formula?

```
A[k_, n_] := 
Sum[KroneckerDelta[GCD[h, k], 1] Exp[
Pi I Sum[(j/k) ((h j)/k - Floor[(h j)/k] - 1/2),
{j, 1,  k - 1}] - (2 Pi I h n)/k], {h, 1, k}]


PartitionsExactP[n_] := 
(1/(Pi Sqrt[2])) Sum[A[k, n] Sqrt[k] D[
Sinh[(Pi Sqrt[2/3] Sqrt[n - 1/24])/k]/(n - 1/24)^(1/2), n], {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

Comment: "Doubtful" would be my most optimistic assessment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for a capability that does not exist in  _Mathematica_.

Comment: So reduce is a nonmatching concept for these possible tasks from the posed problem. The best match is [NonlinearModelFit](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) with a constant, the square root and the log functions as fitting functions of the logarithm of the $p(n)$. The trouble starts with the time consumption of the calcs for the given $p(n)$. So You need an approx already. The infinite sum has to be truncated. The very long runs for the $A(k,n)$ will kill it. Plot approx, asymptotic. Show it graphical. $Sqrt[2/3] \[Pi] Sqrt[x] - 2 Log[2] - Log[3]/2 - Log[x]$